# Jupyter Notebook and previous output

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is there any way to see the previous output without rerunning the program? For example, I left my ML algorithm to work overnight and in the morning I got the results. But, for some reason, when I pressed Enter on the original code, it started to run again and the original output disappeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output exists in a specific context which is the cell and still exist as long as the kernel is still running. If you need to keep the output, you can still save it. For example in files or serialize it with [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

You can also run your script with the command line and save the output in another file :

```
jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute myfile.ipynb --output ./output/myfile.ipynb
```

In this example, I run myfile.ipynb and save the output (which is an ipynb file) in the folder output.

Answer (score 1):

usually, yes, so long as the kernel is still up.  the return values of all expressions evaluated are stored in the `Out` global list.  If you are now executing statement number `n`, then `Out[n-1]` will have the last thing you successfully finished.

if your output was not returned, but rather printed. You're out of luck...

Comment: I have my output printed, not returned -.- Seems like I will have to run it again overnight.