# Is it possible to keep previous output in jupyter notebook when re running the same program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have executed a python program in juypter notebook, I got output for the program as required but I want to keep the output and while re running the program I want to know the previous output, So that I would compare all the outputs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527451/jupyter-notebook-and-previous-output

Comment: question needs to be a bit more specific -- notebooks retain assigned variables and functions between cells

see docs for more details: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Answer (score 0):

While there's probably no built-in way to retain cell output while it's being recalculated, you can split the cell into two separate cells: first will carry on heavy calculations and 2nd one will output the results. This way the results from the calculation (i.e. 2nd cell output) stay on screen while being  recomputed inside the first cell.

Example:

[image]

As you can see, the middle cell takes forever to calculate (minutes in real time), while the bottom cell draws a chart based on the results passed from the middle one, and the chart stays on screen during the recalculation period.